# I'm getting the message "The page has expired due to inactivity" in Laravel 5.5

Tags: google-app-engine, csrf, laravel-5.5, gcloud, csrf-protection

When I run the project locally, everything works perfect. But when I deploy the project in production, I get the message **"The page has expired due to inactivity"** every time I submit a form with POST mnethod.

There are many questions about this problem and I've tried every possible solution:

1- My form contains the token {{ csrf_field() }}
2- I've changed the name of my app (APP_NAME)

The session driver and the cache drive are set to 'file'.

I heard that maybe the storage file is not writable and this is where it stores session. I don't know how to check it, if my project is deployed in GCLoud (Google Cloud Platform).

Thanks

---

**UPDATE 1**

I posted my question in Laracast and someone said that it happens when it can't write on the **storage/sessions** file. When I deploy my project to GCloud, I don't know how to make it writable by the server.

My composer.json file has this config right now:

```
"post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize",
        "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache"
    ]
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

For now I changed the `SESSION_DRIVER` to `cookie` and it works in production.

Comment: It sounds like a bug in your CSRF implementation.  Try turning off CSRF to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks but I already tried turning off my CSRF protection with this :  `protected $except = [
        'your/route'
    ];`. The thing is that I want to keep it.

Comment: As I understand from UPDATE 2 you managed to solve your issue (project working when deployed to production). Can you post an answer under your question so that it will be all clear to other users coming here how you fixed the error? [Answering yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) is perfectly correct in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `SESSION_DRIVER` in your `app.yaml` to cookies, like :

```
env_variables:
 # Put production environment variables here.
 APP_LOG: errorlog
 APP_DEBUG: false

 SESSION_DRIVER : cookie
```